# How do I prove that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{a_{1}}+\frac{1}{a_{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_{n}}}{\sqrt{n}}=?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> let sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ such $a_{1}=1$,and 
>   $$a_{n+1}a_{n}=n,n\ge 1$$
>   show that
>   $$2\sqrt{n}-1\le\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{a_{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}<\dfrac{5}{2}\sqrt{n}-1$$

(2): I consider we can find this limit
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{a_{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}}{\sqrt{n}}=?$$

My try:since
$$a_{n+2}a_{n+1}-a_{n+1}a_{n}=n+1-n=1$$
so
$$a_{n+2}=\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}+a_{n}$$
so
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}=a_{n+2}-a_{n}$$
so
\begin{align*}\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{a_{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}&=a_{1}+(a_{3}-a_{1})+(a_{4}-a_{2})+(a_{5}-a_{3})+\cdots+(a_{n+1}-a_{n-1})\\
&=a_{1}+a_{n+1}+a_{n}-a_{1}-a_{2}\\
&=a_{n+1}+a_{n}-a_{2}
\end{align*}
since $$a_{1}=1,a_{1}a_{2}=1\Longrightarrow a_{2}=1$$
so
$$a_{n+1}+a_{n}-a_{2}\ge2\sqrt{a_{n+1}a_{n}}-1\ge 2\sqrt{n}-1$$

so left hand inequality is prove it.Now consider Right hand inequality,we only prove this
$$a_{n}+a_{n+1}<\dfrac{5}{2}\sqrt{n}$$
since
$$a_{n}a_{n+1}=n\Longrightarrow a_{n}+\dfrac{n}{a_{n}}<\dfrac{5}{2}\sqrt{n}$$
so maybe we can $a_{n}<2\sqrt{n}$?

becasue $$\dfrac{5}{2}\sqrt{n}=2\sqrt{n}+\dfrac{n}{2\sqrt{n}}$$
so let $$f(x)=x+\dfrac{n}{x}$$
if we can prove $a_{n}<2\sqrt{n}$,Then
$$f(x)\le f(2\sqrt{n})=\dfrac{5}{2}\sqrt{n}$$
Thank you very much

Comment: The line including $a_1a_2=1$ should be $a_1a_2=2$ I think

Comment: No,since $a_{n}a_{n+1}=n$,then let $n=1$,we have $a_{1}a_{2}=1$

Comment: Got my indexing wrong, sorry

Answer (score 7):

For even indices
$$
\frac1{a_{2n}}=\frac{(2n-2)!!}{(2n-1)!!}=\frac1{2n}\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\sim\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{2n}
$$
For odd indices
$$
\frac1{a_{2n+1}}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}\sim\frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1{a_k}
&\sim\left(\sqrt\pi+\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\right)\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2n}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}+\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\\[9pt]
&\doteq2.05119869811837
\end{align}
$$

Comment: For odd numbers,this limit is not exsit?+1,Thank you

Comment: It should exist for both odd and even. I only computed an approximation for even numbers since including the next odd term and dividing by $\sqrt{2n+1}$ instead of$\sqrt{2n}$ would not change the value significantly.

Comment: I suspected it had something to do with $\pi$ because, on one hand, it reminded me of the famous [Wallis product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product), and on the other hand $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-1)!!}{(n-2)!!\cdot\sqrt n}$ oscillates inbetween $\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and $\sqrt{2\pi}$. Only that I thought, wrongly, that the limit would be $\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint* : $a_n=\displaystyle\frac{(n-1)!!}{(n-2)!!}$

Comment: Then? I think this idea is very ugly.But Thank you all the same,maybe find limit we use Stloz thereom

Answer (score 2):

observe that for $a_{n}$ to satisfy the inequality $a_{n}+\dfrac{n}{a_{n}}<\dfrac{5}{2}\sqrt{n}$
 we need      $\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{2} <a_{n}<2\sqrt{n}$.

this can be proved by induction: first observe that it is true for $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ then suppose it is true for any n ($a_{n}$) then prove it is true for n+1 ($a_{n+1}$) and you are done