# How prove this sequence inequality $a_{n}+a_{n+1}<\frac{5}{2}\sqrt{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

**Question:**

let sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ such $a_{1}=1$,and $$a_{n+1}a_{n}=n$$
show that

> $$a_{n+1}+a_{n}<\dfrac{5}{2}\sqrt{n}$$

My try: since 
$$a_{1}a_{2}=1\Longrightarrow a_{2}=1$$
so
$$a_{n+1}+a_{n}=a_{n}+\dfrac{n}{a_{n}}$$
let
$$f(x)=\dfrac{n}{x}+x$$

then I can't works,Thank you very much!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586482/how-prove-this-lim-n-to-infty-frac-frac1a-1-frac1a-2-cdots?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Hint:

A natural start would be to generate the formula for calculating $a_{n}$ as a function of $a_{n-1}$ and $n$. That function doesn't lend itself easily to bounding, but there is a related function that is easier to work with.

A quick glance at the series in value form might prove helpful in determining what numbers you need to relate to one another.

```
1: 1
2: 1
3: 2
4: 1.5
5: 2.6666666666666665
6: 1.875
7: 3.2
8: 2.1875
9: 3.657142857142857
10: 2.4609375
11: 4.063492063492063
12: 2.70703125
13: 4.432900432900433
14: 2.9326171875
15: 4.773892773892774
16: 3.14208984375
17: 5.092152292152292
18: 3.338470458984375
19: 5.391690662278897
20: 3.523941040039063
21: 5.675463855030418
22: 3.700138092041016
23: 5.945724038603295
24: 3.8683261871337895
25: 6.204233779412133
26: 4.029506444931031
27: 6.4524031305886185
28: 4.184487462043763
29: 6.691381024314123
30: 4.33393344283104
```